# How to perform a bigquery query in R with a date filter in the query

Tags: r, date, google-bigquery

I have an issue trying to load bigquery data in R and using a date filter (the filter date is variable).

```
projectid = "projectid"

sql <- sprintf("SELECT * 
from [table]

where num_start <21 and t < %s ", paste("'",  Sys.Date() -12, "'", sep=""))
```

I have the following error:

`Error: 4.34 - 4.45: Could not parse '2019-01-04' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]] [invalidQuery]`

Then I changed `Sys.Date()` to `Sys.time()` the query works but I would like to fetch the data n days prior to a the current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using legacy-SQL. Instead, change your query to use standard-SQL and it will for fine then. For example:

```
WITH
  input AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1547636619070) AS ts)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  input
WHERE
  ts > '2019-01-04'
```

[image]

Comment: I am using standard sql (`train_book <- query_exec(sql, project = projectid, useLegacySql = FALSE)`).

Yes it works with a static value but I would like to pass the date to the query as an argument which can change.

Comment: I'm positive that's a legacy-sql error you are seeing. Try prefixing the SQL string with `#standardsql` and see if it works please..

Comment: The query_exec command is described here.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery/versions/1.0.0/topics/query_exec

I have already set it to false in my query: 
`use_legacy_sql
(optional) set to FALSE to enable BigQuery's standard SQL.`

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by prefixing it?

Comment: It's `use_legacy_sql`. You have `useLegacySql`.

Comment: In addition, you're using a deprecated function. _"Please use bq_project_query() instead."_